Uniform dimension of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module
$\textbf{Definition}$: The uniform dimension (Goldie dimension) $\mathrm{u.dim} M$ of a module $M$ is called a such maximal $n \in \mathbb{N}$ that $M$ contains a direct sum $M_1 \oplus \ldots \oplus M_n$ of such $n$ nonzero submodules $M_i$.
I want to try to find the uniform dimension of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-module.
It's well known from CRT that $\mathbb{Z}_n \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$, where $n = n_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot n_k$, and all $n_i$ are relatively prime.
Is the sum $\mathbb{Z}_{n_1} \oplus \ldots \oplus \mathbb{Z}_{n_k}$ maximal in $\mathbb{Z}_n$? What is a number $k$?

The number $k$ is $\omega(n)$, the prime omega function, which is the number of distinct prime factors of $n$. That is, if we factor $n$ into prime powers,
$$n = p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_r^{a_r},$$
with $p_1\lt\cdots\lt p_r$ primes, $a_i\geq 1$, then $n_i=p_i^{a_i}$ and $k=r = \omega(n)$.
Any submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a cyclic subgroup $\mathbb{Z}_d$ with $d\mid n$. By the classification of finite abelian groups, we know that $\mathbb{Z}_r\oplus\mathbb{Z}_s \cong \mathbb{Z}_{\gcd(r,s)}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{\mathrm{lcm}(r,s)}$; so a direct sum of cyclic groups is cyclic if and only if the orders of the summands are relatively prime. Thus, any decomposition of a submodule of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ as a direct sum of submodules must be into submodules of relatively prime order.
Of such decompositions, the one with the most factors is one in which each factor has order a prime power (otherwise we can further decompose that factor). And hence the largest possible number of summands is the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$, $\omega(n)$.

Of such decompositions, the one with the most factors I think it is important to emphasize that uniform dimension is not concerned with maximally-refined decompositions of the module. In this case, it is so, but there are local rings with uniform dimension >2 or even infinite, so the maximally-refined decomposition intuition does not work there.

@rschwieb Right, in general you look at decompositions of both the module and any submodule; but here, because submodules are necessarily cyclic groups, it just devolves into figuring out a maximally refined decomposition of a cyclic group, and that shows that you will achieve the maximum when $d$ has exactly the same number of prime divisors as $n$.

Agreed. I just didn't want a casual reader departing with the impression it was linked with such decompositions.
